# Generalization of an inequaliy related to Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: cauchy-schwarz-inequality

A classic Cauchy-Schwarz problem is to show that if $p_1, p_2 \cdots p_k$ are positive real numbers with $p_1 + p_2 \cdots +p_k=1$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{1}{p_k} +p_k)^2 \geq n^3 +2n + \frac{1}{n}$ with equality if and only if $p_i=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $i$.

It is also not hard to use Cauchy-Schwartz to show that if  $p_1, p_2 \cdots p_k$ are positive real numbers with $p_1 + p_2 \cdots +p_k=1$  then $\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{1}{p_k} +p_k) \geq n^2 +1$.

Taken together, these suggest the following generalization, which I'm hoping to see a proof or disproof of. If $p_1, p_2 \cdots p_k$ are positive real numbers with $p_1 + p_2 \cdots +p_k=1$

$\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{1}{p_k} +p_k)^m  \geq n(\frac{1}{n} +n)^m$ with equality only when the $p_i$ are all equal.

The general inequality is easy to see for $n=2$, from just looking at the function $f(x)=(\frac{1}{x}+x)^m$, since its derivative is zero at $x=1/2$ and then one can apply the first derivative test.

Comment: Use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form)

Comment: @kabenyuk That was my guess but it wasn't clear to me what function to use there. What function do you suggest?

Comment: I think the function you wrote in the last lines of your question will do.

Comment: @kabenyuk Ah yes, you are correct! If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Happy to post my answer.

Comment: However, you must check that this function is convex.

Comment: @kabenyuk Convexity in this case is easy to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Let's use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) for the function
$$
f(x)=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^m.
$$